# Updated or Up-to-date

Tags: grammar

What is the correct term to use if telling someone to make sure his/her  document/record/sign has the most current information. Should it be "Keep your document updated" or "keep the document up-to-date"?

Comment: If keeping it up to date requires them to update it then either is fine and they both end up meaning about the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

"Keep... up-to-date" or "keep current" would be correct here. A thing may be updated yet remain out-of-date, like a month-old software patch.